# Issue with SocketTimeoutException and Jetty

Tags: java, http, servlets, jetty

I'm using a Jetty based servlet to do RPC and I'm having an issue where a request that takes a long time throws the following exception on the server:

> 2012-02-11 21:07:07,673 [btpool0-4]  DEBUG org.mortbay.log - EXCEPTION
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>           at org.mortbay.io.ByteArrayBuffer.readFrom(ByteArrayBuffer.java:168)
>           at org.mortbay.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.fill(StreamEndPoint.java:99)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.fill(SocketConnector
>   .java:190)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:277)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:203)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:357)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.
>   java:217)
>           at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool
>   .java:475) 2012-02-11 21:07:07,674 [btpool0-4]  DEBUG org.mortbay.log
>   - EOF

I tried setting the Connection,Keep-Alive http request property but that had no effect and from what I can gather, http 1.1 (which I'm pretty sure I'm using) is persistent by default.

So I think there are 2 ways I can try to address this:

1. figure out how to prevent the timeout exception from being
   thrown at all
2. Have the client issue the initial request without waiting
   for a response, and then ping with separate requests to check when
   the server is done.

   Update (2/12/2012): I set the maxIdleTime as Tim suggested and that did extend the time before the timeout occurred, but then I started getting a new exception:

> 2012-02-11 23:24:01,187 [btpool0-1]  DEBUG org.mortbay.log - EXCEPTION
>   java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host   at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.fill(ChannelEndPoint.java:129)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:277)   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:203)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:357)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:329)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:475)

So something outside of Jetty was killing the connection, I suspect most likely a firewall. So what I ended up doing was making the server process the request with multiple threads; the original thread would immediately respond to the http request and a second thread would be kicked off to perform the action that was taking a long time. The client would then poll with http requests to check when the action on the server was complete.

Comment: Make the request faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a socket timeout, so nothing you do at the HTTP level can fix it - hence your keep alive not achieving anything.

Try setting the `maxIdleTime` on the `SocketConnector`

See here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+Connectors ( [archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20150526005415/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+Connectors) )

Comment: Codehaus has been terminated.. no enough ad-revenue to cover the hosting and maintenance costs :( And so the link above is no longer working.